# Make SmartImageView not save the image of url

Tags: android

I am using `SmartImageView` to load image from url. But I don't want the `SmartImageView` to save the image because it won't show the new image when the image of url has been changed.

How do I make `SmartImageView` not save the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to [this SmartImageView](https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view/)?

I didn't find a way to turn off the cache programmatically, but it looks like commenting out the implementation for [WebImageCache.put()](https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view/blob/master/src/com/loopj/android/image/WebImageCache.java) should be enough to achieve that, i.e.

```
public void put(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
    // do not cache!
    // cacheBitmapToMemory(url, bitmap);
    // cacheBitmapToDisk(url, bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am referring to this. And thanks, let me try.